# Looking for neat, intuitive, idiomatic way to clip the values I set in NumericUpDown control using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I am using the code below to achieve the functionality I desire: when the user is editing a value in a particular NumericUpDown control, and presses either `k`, `K`, `m`, or `M`, I want the currently entered amount to multiply by `1000`. I also wish to avoid any overflow exceptions. The values should automatically cap at a `minimum` and a `maximum`. I did not want to use `if` statements because `min` and `max` functions are available. But, it takes some mental energy to process that logic (applying `min` to `maximum` and `max` to `minimum` ... what?), and I felt like I needed to leave a comment along the lines of: 'warning, this code is hard to read but it works'. This is not the sort of comment that I should be writing. The logic is too simple to need a comment, and yet I cannot find a self-apparent way to express it. Any suggestions? Could I use settings/methods of the control itself to get this done?

```
    private void quantityNumericUpDown_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control || e.Alt)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            return;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.K && e.KeyCode != Keys.M)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            return;
        }

        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        this.Quantity *= OneThousand;
    }

    private decimal Quantity
    {
        get
        {
            return this.quantityNumericUpDown.Value;
        }

        set
        {
            // Sorry if this is not the most readable.
            // I am trying to avoid an 'out of range' exception by clipping the value at min and max.
            decimal valClippedUp = Math.Min(value, this.quantityNumericUpDown.Maximum);
            this.quantityNumericUpDown.Value = Math.Max(valClippedUp, this.quantityNumericUpDown.Minimum); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this and let the min and max value of the updown control handle it for you.

```
private void ud_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.K ||
        e.KeyCode == Keys.M)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        ud.Value = Math.Max(ud.Minimum, Math.Min(ud.Value * 1000, ud.Maximum));
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this ... it is laconic, but does not it have the same problem - too many min and max on the same line? I think it is hard to get the intent immediately.